# AWK command to fetch a value from the string s-pub-comtec-sap-product-app-1.0.0-mule-app.war

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have a value s-pub-comtec-sap-product-app-1.0.0-mule-application.war
I need to fetch the value 1.0.0 from the above string.

I have used

```
 echo "s-pub-comtec-sap-product-app-1.0.0-mule-application.war" | awk -F '-' '{ print $7 }'
```

and it worked.

But now the problem is sometimes the value will be s-pub-comtec-sap-app-1.0.0-mule-application.war,
in this case my code will not fetch the 1.0.0 value.

Can you please suggest which command will achieve this scenario?

I have given below command which will not work in all the cases.

```
echo "s-pub-comtec-sap-product-app-1.0.0-mule-application.war" | awk -F '-' '{ print $7 }'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the substring you want to extract consists of digits and dots only, preceded by a `-` character, I would suggest a `sed` solution:

```
s='s-pub-comtec-sap-app-1.0.0-mule-application.war'
echo "$s" | sed -E 's/.*-([0-9](\.[0-9]+)+).*/\1/'
```

By the same token, an `awk` solution might be:

```
echo "$s" |
awk 'match($0,/-[0-9](\.[0-9]+)+/) { print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1) }'
```